# Set MaxLength on BaseClass for POCO objects with Fluent API

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a base class, like this  for my POCO objects

```
 public abstract class BASE
    {
        protected BASE()
        {
            Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Modified = Created;

        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

What I want to do is set the "MaxLength(50)" attributes with fluent API.

But if I do this in the `Context.ModelCreating`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BASE>().Property(p => p.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);
modelBuilder.Entity<BASE>().Property(p => p.ModifiedBy).HasMaxLength(50);
```

then "BASEs" table get generated in the database - which I want to avoid.

What am I missing, to be able to set these constraints in Fluent API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` to configure the max length.

Create a base class to map the `BASE` properties.

```
public class MyEntityMap<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : BASE
{
    public MyEntityMap()
    {
        Property(p => p.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(p => p.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

Then create `MyEntityMap<TEntity>` for each derived class.

```
public class DerivedMap : MyEntityMap<Derived>
{
    public DerivedMap()
    {
        //mappings
    }
}

modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DerivedMap());
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used this answer for EF 6 in a Code First approach. The SQL script for setting up the table was produced the way I expected. All Columns mapped in base class where included in the table scripts derived from this class

```
public abstract class BaseMap<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : DbBase
    {
        protected BaseMap()
        {
            Ignore(t => t.DbGuid);

            // Properties

            Property(t => t.CreatedBy)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            Property(t => t.ChangedBy)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            Property(t => t.DeletedBy)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            Property(t => t.RowVersion)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsFixedLength()
                .HasMaxLength(8)
                .IsRowVersion()
                .IsConcurrencyToken();

            // Table & Column Mappings
            Property(t => t.CreatedAt).HasColumnName("CreatedAt");
            Property(t => t.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
            Property(t => t.ChangedAt).HasColumnName("ChangedAt");
            Property(t => t.ChangedBy).HasColumnName("ChangedBy");
            Property(t => t.DeletedAt).HasColumnName("DeletedAt");
            Property(t => t.DeletedBy).HasColumnName("DeletedBy");
            Property(t => t.RowVersion).HasColumnName("RowVersion");
        }
    }
```